# Regex Backeference Multiplying

Tags: python, regex, backreference, quantifiers

I am trying to learn regex and one of the exercise I am trying to solve is as follows:

I have a string:

```
    "london new york"
```

that I am trying match with regex.

and pattern is like this:

```
    r"(..o(.)).+(\2)*"
```

Result is `ndon  new york`.

As far as I understand, (\2) matches `n` but what matches `ew york` ?
Also what does `*` in  `(\2)*` do? Does it try to match `n` or special character `.`?

Comment: `(\2)*` can match an empty string as it is `*` quantified. `.+` effectively matches the whole rest of the line.

Comment: What do you need to achieve here? Please explain the rules, what you need to get and why.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at it like this

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      . . o
      ( . )                         # (2)
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( .+ )                        # (3)
 ( \2 )*                       # (4)
```

---

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 2 : len 13 ) 
ndon new york  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 2 : len 4 ) 
ndon  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 5 : len 1 ) 
n  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 6 : len 9 ) 
 new york  
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL
```

You can see that group 4 is always empty.
Group 4 *will* always be empty, because group 3, takes all
the *air* out of the remainder of the current line, never
leaving anything for ***Optional Group 4***.

You still must be careful when you use quantifier `*` or `+` on
capture groups. That is because each iteration of the *group*,
if matched will contribute to the whole match, however only the
last iteration will be retained by that group because it's
contents are overwritten each time.